# Undefined method `model_name' in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Basically i have a table with a lot of activities, each activity has a sport , and i want to link the name of the activity (that is also the name of the name of the sport which the activity is associated to) to the correspondent sport page, and i am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for Sport::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class
```

The view here i get the error:

```
<% @activity.each do |activity| %>
<tr>
<td><%= link_to activity.id, activity_path(activity) %></td>
<td><%= link_to activity.name, searchsport(activity.name) %></td> //error here//
<td><%= activity.ambiente %></td>
<td><%= activity.resume %></td>
<td><%= activity.duration %></td>
```

I have this helper method in the controller:

```
  helper_method :searchsport
  def searchsport(name)
    Sport.where(:name => name)
  end
```

Sports table:

```
  create_table "sports", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `link_to` in the following ways

```
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile)
link_to "Profile", @profile
link_to "Profile", controller: "profiles", action: "show", id: @profile
```

So it either takes a `url, or an active record object or a hash`. What you are giving is a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. so you will have to change your helper method to return an object like below

```
 helper_method :searchsport
  def searchsport(name)
    Sport.where(:name => name).first
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the method **searchsport** returns an array of results modify it to get one record.

```
def searchsport(name)
 Sport.find_by_name(name)
end
```